# Unable to loosen IXOW Wheelguard Gravity nut

Tags: wheels, tools

I have a Canyon Commuter 7.0 which uses [IXOW Wheelguard Gravity](http://ixow.com/product/wheelguard-gravity/) skewers and nut. I want to take my front wheel off but am unable to loosen the nut on the front skewer.

The standard procedure is to flip the bike upside down and then loosen the nut. This does not work. The instructions state that if the nut cannot be loosened, it should be tightened a little before loosening as doing this should release the locking mechanism. This approach worked for the nut on the seatpost clamp (which uses the same type of nut), but has not worked for the front wheel.

The recommended tightness for the front wheel nut is 5-7Nm. I've already increased it to 8Nm when tightening in an attempt to loosen - it slipped at this point, so I don't want to try much more force in case I damage it.

I've tried flipping the bike upside down a few times, to no avail. What else can I do to try and loosen the nut?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I contacted both Canyon and IXOW but as of now, haven't received a reply from either.

Comment: @MikkoS see my comment in the answer - what's important is not that the bike is upside down, but that the lock icon is upside down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Exact same problem here. Same bike. I got it off finally by just turning really really hard using a non-torque wrench. Make sure it's rotated so that the two dots are UP (12 o'clock). If installed correctly the lock should be at 12 o'clock when wheels are on the ground. So if you installed it in the wrong orientation (i.e. lock at 2 o'clock or 9 o'clock etc), then turning it upside down will not be the correct position. So rotate the bicycle around until the two dots are at 12 o'clock.

You can see from my photo it seems that when tried to loosen it, the tab on the black washer that is suppose to be in the fork dropout rolled into the plastic dropout insert which was causing it to bind. Going to write Canyon about this to see how I can get it repaired. Same thing happen to you?

Explained in the instructions from IXOW--packaged separately from the urban manual.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I worked out the issue late last night. I hadn't installed it at the right orientation - I didn't see anything in the Canon docs to suggest the lock icon needs to point upwards - so flipping the bike upside down was never going to work. It was only from looking at the IXOW docs that I realised I hadn't installed it as intended.

Comment: @PaulCarey did you figure out how to install the mudguard? I'm not sure which end of the support bars I should put the spacers? I'm thinking maybe the mudguard end, otherwise the clearance with the wheel is very tight.

Comment: @PaulCarey the IXOW manual is packaged separately from the urban manual. I updated the answer with an image.  When lock is up, you can only tighten the bolt; when two dots are up, you can tighten and loosen it.

Comment: @ maxhodges : You will find instruction here for the mudguard :
https://www.canyon.com/service/supportcenter/article.html?supportcenter_articles_id=301

Comment: You did right to not use a torque wrench to undo things.  That's not what they're for.  You can't reliably measure the torque doing this anyway; you just risk putting your precision measuring tool out of calibration.  For more leverage, use a breaker bar and the correct sized socket or 1/4" bit.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because I did not install the lock in the right orientation (lock icon needs to point upwards). When trying to unlock I damaged the plastic dropout insert (see photo in answer of maxhodges).  After I discovered the wrong installation (thanks to answer of maxhodges) I was still not able to loosen the bolt because the tab on the washer simply slipped through the damaged dropout. I solved this by (gently) inserting a screwdriver between tab and dropout to fix the tab. Loosening the bolt was then easy.

Answer (score 2):

i did the same mistake at first. and I tried to reach Canyon Service Hotline both by livechat and telefone. unfortunately neither of them worked.

back to the topic, what you need to do is to adjust your bike into any position where the two DOTs on the IXOW Nut is on the TOP. If you are not sure if you are doing it right, refer to the DOTs position of the back wheel when you turn your bike up-side-down.

Canyon offers absolute great bikes. But i have seen much better assembling guidebooks, e.g. IKEA. Maybe they could spend some more effort on that.

Comment: That's a good point - thank you for contributing.   Welcome to SE, do have a browse of the [tour] to see how things are a bit different here compared to other chatty web forums.