# Plastic insert damaged when tried to open gravity wheelguard ixow

Tags: wheels, commuter, fork, parts, replacement

Can anyone tell me where I can find to buy the plastic insert from the wheelguard?[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what it is you need, can you explain what it is for?

Comment: Oh these things http://thebestbikelock.com/wheel-locks-and-seat-locks/ixow-security-system-review/

Comment: Looks like it is nothing to do with the axle locking system.  Is your bike a Canyon like in https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31799/   ?

Comment: I need the black plastic insert marked in the picture. The one from the picture is in good shape, but the another one from the other side is broken. I completely damaged it when I tried to open the ixow system.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness - this is a part custom to your brand and model of frame.  It doesn't seem to be related to your choice of wheel skewer.

So your best option is to contact the manufacturer of your frame directly, or their authorised agents in your area.

Based on the linked question, you have a Canyon Commuter, and their contact information for you is based in Koblenz, Germany.  https://www.canyon.com/en-ro/contact/  You can use telephone, live chat, or email.